# Show Tooltip inside div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, tooltip

I have few menu , i am showing them in left navigation bar

```
 <li><a href= @RoleGroup><i class="menu-icon fa fa-users"></i> <span class="title"> Group Management</span></a></li>
```

I want to show Tooltip (4-5 lines) on mouse over inside a div.
In above code how i can place tooltip inside div with good css style.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a Look at [hint.css](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make the text of the element you're hovering over display in another div? We'd need more code to really get this but here's a start:

```
$('.ulClass li').mouseover(function(){
     var myText = $(this).text();
     $(divIwantTextToShowIn).text(myText);
 });

$('.ulClass li').mouseleave(function(){

     $(divIwantTextToShowIn).text("");
 });
```

That will display the text from the li that you hover over in another div. I'm guessing that is what you're looking for. When the mouse cursor leaves the li it will clear the text of the div.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the TipTip library, you can do it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".someClass").tipTip();
});



<p>
    Cras sed ante. Phasellus in massa. <a href="" class="someClass" title="This will show up in the TipTip popup.">Curabitur dolor eros</a>, gravida et, hendrerit ac, cursus non, massa.
    <span id="foo">
        <img src="image.jpg" class="someClass" title="A picture of the World" />
    </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the title attribute in a element.

Ex:
`<li title=" here is the tool tip that i want "> ...  </li>`

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp

Comment: However, as dfsq commented, try using a library to do this, they tend to be faster and more consistent between browsers.

Comment: title is good, but not styleable so probably not what OP wants